# ajax enabling problem

Tags: asp.net-ajax

Hello friends a day ago i made my visual studio(2005, 2.0) ajax enabled.
But i am already having a web site which is not ajax enabled so how can i make that ajax enabled. Because it doesn't recognize script manager tag and update panel tag on putting .
While whenever i make a new web site it ask for ajax enable web site but how can i make my existing web site ajax enable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest creating a new ajax enabled web site, and carefully comparing its web.config with your current site's web.config. That should help you identify the critical points.

Comment: after carefully observation it was done in without master page site.
But my site having master page it is not making it ajax enable what to do is there any special changes require for this

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your original question. Usually, when I think about ajax-enabling a site, I think about what assembly references, scripts, and configuration are necessary to provide an ajax-oriented architecture for development. Perhaps if you can provide more information about what specific issues you are having, we can be a little more helpful.